# Changing height of strip text background in ggplot2 does not work as expected ggplot2 V 2.2.0

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

#### Load libraries

```
library(ggplot2) #Version 2.2.1
library(gtable)
```

#### Build plot

```
d <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=gear)) + 
            geom_bar(aes(y=gear), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
            facet_wrap(~cyl)
```

#### Aim: change height of strip text

```
g <- ggplotGrob(d)
g$heights[[3]] = unit(2,"in")
g$grobs[[5]]$heights <- g$grobs[[6]]$heights <-
    g$grobs[[7]]$heights <- unit(1, "native") # or "npc"
grid.newpage()
```

#### Expected result (as per the old ggplot 2.1.0)

[image]

#### Problem: Obtained result (in ggplot2 2.2.1)

[image]

The above solution is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35043190/changing-height-of-strip-text-background-in-ggplot2-does-not-work-as-expected) and worked fine in ggplot2 version 2.1.0.

How then should the strip background height modification be done in ggplot2 V 2.2.1? Many thanks folks!

Comment: Isn't something like `+theme(strip.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(1, 0.5, 1, 0, "cm")))`enough?

Comment: As @Haboryme suggests, use `margins` in `strip,text` elements (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41428344/edit-strip-size-ggplot2/41428958#41428958)). But, in your code, the index for the heights is 6, and the indices for the three grobs are 17, 18, and 19.